# How to get Locust worker ID?

Tags: python, locust

I ran into one problem when tried to write some tests for load testing using Locust.

The idea: I have to link a specific locust worker (thread) to a specific account. For example:

```
thread #1 will use only account1,password1

thread #2 will use only account2,password2
```

But I did not find any option how to do this. Could anyone help with this issue or give an advice with a workaround? Thanks in adcance!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the greenlet id of the currently running locust by using greenlet.getcurrent().minimal_ident

This id is not global, so if you run master-slave you may need to differentiate between slaves, if you need some kind of globally unique identifier (but I'm guessing you dont :)